# Birghtcove chromeless video player controls not working in Safari

Tags: javascript, html, flash, object, brightcove

Issue is happening with BrightCove's Chromeless player

The controls (pause, play, and move to a specific time in the video) appear on hover but when clicked they just disappear (instead of pausing/playing or moving to a specified time).

They appear and work in Firefox and Chrome... :(

Here is my configuration:

```
<object id={this.props.elemId} className="BrightcoveExperience">
        <param name="allowFullScreen" value="false" />
        <param name="bgcolor" value="#000000" />
        <param name="width" value="960" />
        <param name="playerID" value="**********" />
        <param name="playerKey" value="**********" />
        <param name="height" value="540" />
        <param name="isUI" value="true" />
        <param name="isVid" value="true" />
        <param name="dynamicStreaming" value="true" />
        <param name="includeAPI" value="true" />
        <param name="showNoContentMessage" value="true" />
        <param name="htmlFallback" value="true" />
        <param name="seamlesstabbing" value="false" />
        <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
        <param name="templateLoadHandler" value={this.onTemplateLoaded} />
        <param name="autoStart" value={this.props.autoplay} />
        <param name="@videoPlayer"  value={this.props.id} />
</object>
```

Comment: Without the values you've obfuscated this can't be reproduced. If you cannot provide a [mcve] here, this question should be directed directly to Brightcove's support.

Comment: Apologies, so I can't reveal the player ID or Key because it's proprietary I believe (not completely sure how Brightcove works else I might not have this issue), however it's the Chromeless player if that helps?

Comment: Doesn't help unfortunately as a standard Chrome Video Player works fine on Safari. Again, if you're not in a position to post complete details you'd be much better off using the support that Brightcove provides.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else runs into this issue and finds this post, the cause was that I was applying a CSS transform to the container element for the Brightcove video.

No idea why this caused issues, found a few SO questions and posts talking about CSS transforms breaking flash players in old versions of Firefox but nothing about breaking in current Safari.

Oddly I think the bug may only occur when the transform is applied to the parent (transforms on the player itself are okay I think).

Fortunately in my case we were able to achieve the same styling effect without transforms.